# How do I handle errors in my app when there seems to be none

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I'm a brand new programmer. I'm about to finish my first simple todo list app using core data. The app works perfectly and never crashes. It doesn't require internet connection to work and I don't think there are any possible errors in the app since I made sure everything works fine. By reading apple developer's website, I understand that you need to handle possible errors properly before submitting it for review, but my question is, would I need to handle errors if there can't be any?

Comment: Any errors, you need delete all NSLOG's too. As you do not use the Internet to share content believe you will have no problem publishing your app.

if you app crash, for any reason apple can't publish your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! So basically you're saying that my app probably won't have any problems to be published?

Comment: If your app dont crash, he will be published.

Comment: Alright that's awesome. Again thanks a lot ErasmoOliveira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this.

Let the set of **possible errors** be `E`.
Apple's guidelines insist that your app be robust enough that should an error `e` in `E` occur, the application handle it without crashing. This could be displaying a modal dialog informing the user of the issue; ignoring or accounting for the error and then continuing silently; changing the UI to reflect the change in process state; or any number of non-crashing control paths.

You have stated for your application that the size of the set `E` is `0`. Since there are no elements within the set, you have handled all of the errors, implying that your assertion that you have handled all errors is **vacuously true**.

Comment: I've made sure that every function and possible data returns some values. For example when I ask the user to input a task, the compiler will expect a string. I've made it so that if it's empty it will return an empty string. Dates will return today's date by default. So I'm pretty sure there cannot be any errors. Plus the app never crashes. Thanks so much for the help, this is great news for me!